# Scroll position after reload Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a little problem with the scroll recharge after data via ajax, I step to show ..

> Js

```
$('select#mes').on('change',function(){
        var valor = $(this).val();
        var route = "../../public/ADIC/ListaM";
        var token = document.getElementById('token').getAttribute('content')

        if(valor != null){

        $.ajax({
        url: route,
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{mes: valor},
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#resultado").html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>');
                $('#limpiar tbody').empty();
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#resultado").html('');  

                var tbody = $('.table.table-striped > tbody');
                    $(data.users).each(function(index, user){
                        if(user.Check_J1 == 1 && user.Check_J2 == 1 ){
                            $('<tr class="success" />')
                            .append($('<td />').html(user.Fecha))
                            .append($('<td />').html(user.Cancha))
                            .append($('<td />').html(user.EquipoA +' vs '+ user.EquipoB + ' (' + user.Categoria +')' ))
                            .append($('<td />').html(user.Numero_J1 +' - '+ user.Nombre_J1 + ' ' + user.Apellido_J1 ))
                            .append($('<td />').html(user.Numero_J2 +' - '+ user.Nombre_J2 + ' ' + user.Apellido_J2 ))
                            .append($('<td />').html('<button class="btn register  btn-skin-green btn-xs" data-store-code='+ user.id +' ><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i>Ver</button>'))
                            .appendTo(tbody);
                        }else{
                            $('<tr class="danger" />')
                            .append($('<td />').html(user.Fecha))
                            .append($('<td />').html(user.Cancha))
                            .append($('<td />').html(user.EquipoA +' vs '+ user.EquipoB + ' (' + user.Categoria +')' ))
                            .append($('<td />').html(user.Numero_J1 +' - '+ user.Nombre_J1 + ' ' + user.Apellido_J1 ))
                            .append($('<td />').html(user.Numero_J2 +' - '+ user.Nombre_J2 + ' ' + user.Apellido_J2 ))
                            .append($('<td />').html('<button class="btn register  btn-skin-green btn-xs" data-store-code='+ user.id +' ><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i>Ver</button>'))
                            .appendTo(tbody);
                        }                   
                    });
                $('.register').click(function() {
                    var storeCode = $(this).data('storeCode');
                    $("#capa_modal").show();
                    $("#capa_para_edicion").show();
                    var url = storeCode+"/edit"; 
                        $.get(url,function(resul){
                            $("#capa_para_edicion").html(resul);
                        });
                });
            },
            error: function() {

            }
        });
        }else{
        }
    });
```

This java what it does is collect the variable of a selectbox and makes an ajax statement to collect data and displaying in a table

at the same time creates a button that opens a modal window with posivilidad to modify the information.

> viwer

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-1'></div>
        <div class='col-md-10'>
        @foreach($resp as $respuesta)
            {!!Form::hidden('id',$respuesta->id, ['id'=>'id'])!!}

            {!!Form::label('numero','Fecha: ')!!}
            {!!$respuesta->Fecha!!}<br>
            {!!Form::label('numero','Cancha: ')!!}
            {!!$respuesta->Cancha!!}<br>
            {!!Form::label('nombre','Partido: ')!!}
            {!!$respuesta->EquipoA!!} vs {!!$respuesta->EquipoB!!}({!!$respuesta->Categoria!!})<br>

            <div id="datos1">
            {!!Form::label('nombre','Primer Juez: ')!!}
            @if($respuesta->Check_J1 == '1')
                {!!$respuesta->Numero_J1!!} - {!!$respuesta->Nombre_J1!!} {!!$respuesta->Apellido_J1!!} <span class="btn label label-success">ok</span>
                <span id="show_1" class=" btn label label-warning">Editar</span></a><br>
            @else
                {!!$respuesta->Numero_J1!!} - {!!$respuesta->Nombre_J1!!} {!!$respuesta->Apellido_J1!!} <span class="btn label label-danger" >Error</span>


                <span id="1_juez" class="btn label label-primary">
                @foreach($Juez1 as $Juez1)
                    {!!$Juez1->numero1!!} - {!!$Juez1->nombre1!!} {!!$Juez1->apellido1!!}</span>
                    {!!Form::hidden('Numero_J1',$Juez1->numero1, ['id'=>'Numero_J1'])!!}
                    {!!Form::hidden('Nombre_J1',$Juez1->nombre1, ['id'=>'Nombre_J1'])!!}
                    {!!Form::hidden('Apellido_J1',$Juez1->apellido1, ['id'=>'Apellido_J1'])!!}
                @endforeach
                <span id="show_1" class=" btn label label-warning">Editar</span></a><br>

            @endif
            </div>
            <div id=edit_1>
                <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-md-2'>
                {!!Form::text('Numero_J1_e',$respuesta->Numero_J1, ['id'=>'Numero_J1_e','class'=>'form-control input-sm ', 'placeholder' => 'Numero'])!!}
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-3'>
                {!!Form::text('Nombre_J1_e',$respuesta->Nombre_J1, ['id'=>'Nombre_J1_e','class'=>'form-control input-sm', 'placeholder' => 'Nombre'])!!}
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-5'>
                {!!Form::text('Apellido_J1_e',$respuesta->Apellido_J1, ['id'=>'Apellido_J1_e','class'=>'form-control input-sm', 'placeholder' => 'Apellido'])!!}
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-2'>
                <span id="1_juez_e" class=" btn label label-success">Confirmar</span></a>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        <div id="datos2">
            {!!Form::label('nombre','Segundo Juez: ')!!}
            @if($respuesta->Check_J2 == '1')
                {!!$respuesta->Numero_J2!!} - {!!$respuesta->Nombre_J2!!} {!!$respuesta->Apellido_J2!!} <span class="btn label label-success">ok</span>
                <span id="show_2" class=" btn label label-warning">Editar</span></a><br><br>
            @else
                {!!$respuesta->Numero_J2!!} - {!!$respuesta->Nombre_J2!!} {!!$respuesta->Apellido_J2!!} <span class="btn label label-danger" >Error</span>

            @foreach($Juez2 as $Juez2)
            @if($Juez2->numero2 !='')
                <span id="2_juez" class="btn label label-primary">
                    {!!$Juez2->numero2!!} - {!!$Juez2->nombre2!!} {!!$Juez2->apellido2!!}</span>
                    {!!Form::hidden('Numero_J2',$Juez2->numero2, ['id'=>'Numero_J2'])!!}
                    {!!Form::hidden('Nombre_J2',$Juez2->nombre2, ['id'=>'Nombre_J2'])!!}
                    {!!Form::hidden('Apellido_J2',$Juez2->apellido2, ['id'=>'Apellido_J2'])!!}

            @else
                No hay datos
            @endif
            @endforeach
                <span id="show_2" class=" btn label label-warning">Editar</span></a><br>

            @endif
            </div>

             <div id=edit_2>
                    <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-md-2'>
                    {!!Form::text('Numero_J2_e',$respuesta->Numero_J2, ['id'=>'Numero_J2_e','class'=>'form-control input-sm ', 'placeholder' => 'Numero'])!!}
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-md-3'>
                    {!!Form::text('Nombre_J2_e',$respuesta->Nombre_J2, ['id'=>'Nombre_J2_e','class'=>'form-control input-sm', 'placeholder' => 'Nombre'])!!}
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-md-5'>
                    {!!Form::text('Apellido_J2_e',$respuesta->Apellido_J2, ['id'=>'Apellido_J2_e','class'=>'form-control input-sm', 'placeholder' => 'Apellido'])!!}
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-md-2'>
                    <span id="2_juez_e" class=" btn label label-success">Confirmar</span></a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {!!Form::hidden('valor',$respuesta->Mes, ['id'=>'valor'])!!}
        @endforeach


        <a id="salir" class="label label-danger "><i class='fa fa-link'></i> <span>Volver</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>          
</div>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#edit_1").hide();
    $("#edit_2").hide();

    $('#show_1').click(function(f) {  
        $("#edit_1").slideToggle();
    });
    $('#show_2').click(function(r) {  
        $("#edit_2").slideToggle();
    });

    $('#1_juez').click(function(e) {  
        var dato = $("#id").val();
        var dato1 = $("#Numero_J1").val();
        var dato2 = $("#Nombre_J1").val();
        var dato3 = $("#Apellido_J1").val();

        var route = "http://localhost/UJOBB/public/ADIC/edito1";

        var token = document.getElementById('token').getAttribute('content')

        $.ajax({
        url: route,
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{id: dato, Numero_J1: dato1, Nombre_J1: dato2, Apellido_J1: dato3},
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#datos1").html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>');
                },
                success: function() {
                    $("#datos1").load(dato+"/edit" + " #datos1");
                    $("#edit_1").hide();
                },
                error: function() {

                }
            });
        $("#edit_1").hide();
    });

    $('#2_juez').click(function(e) {  
        var dato = $("#id").val();
        var dato1 = $("#Numero_J2").val();
        var dato2 = $("#Nombre_J2").val();
        var dato3 = $("#Apellido_J2").val();

        var route = "http://localhost/UJOBB/public/ADIC/edito2";

        var token = document.getElementById('token').getAttribute('content')

        $.ajax({
        url: route,
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{id: dato, Numero_J2: dato1, Nombre_J2: dato2, Apellido_J2: dato3},
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#datos2").html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>');
                },
                success: function() {
                    $("#datos2").load(dato+"/edit" + " #datos2");
                    $("#edit_2").hide();
                },
                error: function() {

                }
            });
        $("#edit_2").hide();
    });

    $('#1_juez_e').click(function(e) {  
        var dato = $("#id").val();
        var dato1 = $("#Numero_J1_e").val();
        var dato2 = $("#Nombre_J1_e").val();
        var dato3 = $("#Apellido_J1_e").val();

        var route = "http://localhost/UJOBB/public/ADIC/edito1";

        var token = document.getElementById('token').getAttribute('content')

        $.ajax({
        url: route,
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{id: dato, Numero_J1: dato1, Nombre_J1: dato2, Apellido_J1: dato3},
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#datos1").html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>');
                },
                success: function() {
                    $("#datos1").load(dato+"/edit" + " #datos1");
                    $("#edit_1").hide();
                },
                error: function() {

                }
            });
    });

    $('#2_juez_e').click(function(f) {  
        var dato = $("#id").val();
        var dato1 = $("#Numero_J2_e").val();
        var dato2 = $("#Nombre_J2_e").val();
        var dato3 = $("#Apellido_J2_e").val();

        var route = "http://localhost/UJOBB/public/ADIC/edito2";

        var token = document.getElementById('token').getAttribute('content')

        $.ajax({
        url: route,
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{id: dato, Numero_J2: dato1, Nombre_J2: dato2, Apellido_J2: dato3},
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#datos2").html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>');
                },
                success: function() {
                    $("#datos2").load(dato+"/edit" + " #datos2");
                    $("#edit_2").hide();
                },
                error: function() {

                }
            });
    });

    $('#salir').click(function() {
    //funcion para ocultar las capas modales
        var valor = $("#valor").val();
        $("#capa_modal").hide();
        $("#capa_para_edicion").hide();
        $("#capa_para_edicion").html("");

        var route = "../../public/ADIC/ListaM";
        var token = document.getElementById('token').getAttribute('content')

        $.ajax({
        url: route,
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{mes: valor},
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#resultado").html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>');
                $('#limpiar tbody').empty();
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#resultado").html('');  

                var tbody = $('.table.table-striped > tbody');

                $(data.users).each(function(index, user){
                    if(user.Check_J1 == 1 && user.Check_J2 == 1 ){
                        $('<tr class="success" />')
                        .append($('<td />').html(user.Fecha))
                        .append($('<td />').html(user.Cancha))
                        .append($('<td />').html(user.EquipoA +' vs '+ user.EquipoB + ' (' + user.Categoria +')' ))
                        .append($('<td />').html(user.Numero_J1 +' - '+ user.Nombre_J1 + ' ' + user.Apellido_J1 ))
                        .append($('<td />').html(user.Numero_J2 +' - '+ user.Nombre_J2 + ' ' + user.Apellido_J2 ))
                        .append($('<td />').html('<button class="btn register  btn-skin-green btn-xs" data-store-code='+ user.id +' ><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i>Ver</button>'))
                        .appendTo(tbody);
                    }else{
                        $('<tr class="danger" />')
                        .append($('<td />').html(user.Fecha))
                        .append($('<td />').html(user.Cancha))
                        .append($('<td />').html(user.EquipoA +' vs '+ user.EquipoB + ' (' + user.Categoria +')' ))
                        .append($('<td />').html(user.Numero_J1 +' - '+ user.Nombre_J1 + ' ' + user.Apellido_J1 ))
                        .append($('<td />').html(user.Numero_J2 +' - '+ user.Nombre_J2 + ' ' + user.Apellido_J2 ))
                        .append($('<td />').html('<button class="btn register  btn-skin-green btn-xs" data-store-code='+ user.id +' ><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i>Ver</button>'))
                        .appendTo(tbody);
                    }            
                });
                $('.register').click(function() {
                    var storeCode = $(this).data('storeCode');
                    $("#capa_modal").show();
                    $("#capa_para_edicion").show();
                    var url = storeCode+"/edit"; 
                        $.get(url,function(resul){
                            $("#capa_para_edicion").html(resul);
                        });
                });
            },
        })
    });   
});




</script>
```

to close the window reloads the information to show the changes that were made ...

the problem is that when the information recharges the scroll up to the top,

and if you're in the last row is very troublesome back down to where you stayed ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the end you can do with a small cycle

```
var y = $(document).scrollTop();
```

y is the variable that determines the position of the scroll, place it in the js ...

```
$(document).scrollTop(y);
```

and then after reloading the table, place the statement that causes the scroll down to the previous poscision